# Bluetooth LE pairing through app and system settings

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have implemented bluetooth LE in my android app and I can connect and disconnect to device successfully, but when I am paired with device, I cannot see it any longer in my system bluetooth devices list. My question is: is it possible to connect to device through app, see it as paired in system settings and then disconnect it from system settings?